# Apps script error to sync google form responses with google fusion tables

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-fusion-tables

Can anyone advise how to get the google apps script working so form responses (held in a spreadsheet) automatically update in my fusion table?

Following the google tutorial guidance, I replaced the spreadsheet placeholder script with this code:

http://fusion-tables-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/FusionTablesFormSync/src/formsync.js

But...I now get this TypeError:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/lmpkfk6ztc0kjla/Screen%20Shot%202014-02-20%20at%2012.42.49.pdf

And after initially receiving the spreadsheet data, my fusion table is now not updating new entries on the responses spreadsheet. This spreadsheet does update fine with new responses from the form.

I'm not a coder so am finding this quite a challenge :)

Thanks.